# How do I modify parameters stored by functools.wraps?

Tags: python, functools

I have a decorator that validates some parameters and passes an validated key to various functions:

```
from functools import wraps

ref validate(f):
    @wraps(f) # This is to ensure docstrings are passed through the decorated function
    def redirect_if_invalid(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.valid == False:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login')
        else:
            newkwargs = { 'key': request.key }
        return f(request, *args, **newkwargs)
return redirect_if_invalid
```

This is used by some other functions:

```
@validate
def genericHandler(request, key)
   pass
```

I'd call the function like this:

```
genericHandler(request)
```

And the decorator generates the 'key' kwarg.  However, I'd like to optionally pass in the key at some other point, ie call:

```
genericHandler(request, 'keydata')
```

Currently this gives me an error:

```
TypeError: genericHandler() got multiple values for keyword argument 'key'
```

How can I get around this?  To reiterate, the main goal is to be able to call genericHandler() with or without the optional parameter, and have the decorator generate the parameter only if it's missing.

So far inside the decorator, I can't figure out how to determine whether the 'key' parameter was passed in or not because functools.wraps() seems to hide it.

Comment: Why do you say `functools.wrap` hides it? `"key"` ends up right there in `args`, so you could do `if len(args) == 0:...`. Is the problem that it doesn't know what the position of "key" is?

Comment: Put differently: What behavior is different when the `wraps(f)` line is included as opposed to when it isn't?

Comment: Yeah, this decorator is used on a number of functions, where 'key' is in various positions.

Comment: Typo: "ref" instead of "def" in first code block

Answer (score 1):

There's not any reasonable way to do this if you want your wrapper's signature to still be `(request, *args, **kwargs)`. On the other hand, it looks like your decorator already assumes that the wrapped function takes a `key` parameter, so why not rewrite the wrapper to take one as well? In that case it becomes trivial to check if it's been passed or not.

```
def validate(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def redirect_if_invalid(request, key=None):
        # do the validation
        if key is None:
            key = request.key
        return f(request, key)
    return redirect_if_invalid
```

You can add the `*args` and `**kwargs` parameters back if you like, of course.

Comment: I'm going to try this out.  It's non-optimal because the @validate decorator is used for a number of functions that have a variety of argument lists, so I think I'll have to modify all of those functions.  It might not be that bad.

Comment: This somewhat works, except when the decorated function f is a django request handler, and 'key' is not parameter that's passed in via the normal django routing.

Answer (score 0):

So the best way for me to do this was to explicitly pass kwargs as kwargs.  So decorated functions should actually be:

```
@validate
def genericHandler(request, **kwargs)
    key = kwargs.get('key')
    pass
```

This way, I can call the function either with or without args:

```
genericHandler(request)
```

or

```
genericHandler(request, **{ 'key' : key })
```

And the actual decorated looks like:

```
def validate(f):
    @wraps(f) # This is to ensure docstrings are passed through the decorated function
    def redirect_if_invalid(request, *args, **kwargs):
        key = kwargs.get('key')
        if not key:
            kwargs.set('key', request.key)
        return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return redirect_if_invalid
```